# log4j logs not creating in ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, log4j

I created java maven application with log4j logging.

In windows it is working. Log files are created in the path which is given the log4j.properties. log4j.properties is in maven resource folder.

But when buliding jar with maven install from eclipse, and running it from ubuntu, log files are not creating. Modified the log4j.properties with linux path.

```
# Root logger option, logs messages for the all classes in the application
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# log for myproj.sample.Aaa class
log4j.logger.myproj.sample.Aaa = DEBUG,aaa
log4j.appender.aaa = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.aaa.file = /home/ushusadmin/aaa.log
log4j.appender.aaa.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.aaa.append = true
log4j.appender.aaa.MaxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.aaa.MaxBackupIndex=7
log4j.additivity.aaa=false
```

Below given the code for logging in Aaa class.

```
public static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Aaa.class.getName());

LOG.debug("haiii");
```

Comment: Can you share some part of codes ? How you initialize log4j ? How is your log4j.properties file content ?

Comment: Is the path valid in Linux? Does the application have write-permission?

Comment: How to check application has write permission?

Comment: I added the properties file